# I get an error fatal error: runtime: out of memory while downloading video using 'go-ipfs-api'

Tags: go

I used `go-ipfs-api` to download a large file from ipfs, web access download.

I get an error fatal error:

> runtime: out of memory.

How can I modify my code?

```
func main()  {
    http.HandleFunc("/", download)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func download(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    client := shell.NewShell("http://127.0.0.1:5001")

    fd, err := client.Cat("QmTcj7SfRf4vnLnCqnxMT7kutrzFyevjBeT5RCiN9xGAL4")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer fd.Close()

    fileName := "demo.mp4"
    // As per RFC6266 section 4.3
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=utf-8''"+ fileName)

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(fd)

    http.ServeContent(w, r, fileName, time.Now().Local(), bytes.NewReader(data))

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    return
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of ReadAll, you can use io.Copy, but you have to set the content type yourself:

```
w.Header.Set("Content-Type",<the content type>)
io.Copy(w,fd)
return
```

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, you may need to call fd.Close() after copy.